# OpenVINO tensorflow model optimizer error

Tags: tensorflow, openvino

I'm getting the following error when i try to convert my trained tensorflow model to IR

> Model Optimizer arguments:
> Common parameters:
> - Path to the Input Model:  None
> - Path for generated IR:    /home/ec2-user/Notebooks/.
> - IR output name:   saved_model
> - Log level:    ERROR
> - Batch:    Not specified, inherited from the model
> - Input layers:     Not specified, inherited from the model
> - Output layers:    Not specified, inherited from the model
> - Input shapes:     [1,512,512,3]
> - Mean values:  Not specified
> - Scale values:     Not specified
> - Scale factor:     Not specified
> - Precision of IR:  FP32
> - Enable fusing:    True
> - Enable grouped convolutions fusing:   True
> - Move mean values to preprocess section:   None
> - Reverse input channels:   False
> TensorFlow specific parameters:
> - Input model in text protobuf format:  False
> - Path to model dump for TensorBoard:   None
> - List of shared libraries with TensorFlow custom layers implementation:    None
> - Update the configuration file with input/output node names:   None
> - Use configuration file used to generate the model with Object Detection API:  None
> - Use the config file:  None
> Model Optimizer version:    2021.1.0-1237-bece22ac675-releases/2021/1
> 2021-01-06 09:55:53.886652: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/intel/openvino_2021/data_processing/dl_streamer/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/data_processing/gstreamer/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/opencv/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/ngraph/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl_unite/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/gna/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/mkltiny_lnx/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/tbb/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64
> 2021-01-06 09:55:53.886685: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> 2021-01-06 09:55:57.571164: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/intel/openvino_2021/data_processing/dl_streamer/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/data_processing/gstreamer/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/opencv/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/ngraph/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl_unite/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/gna/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/mkltiny_lnx/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/tbb/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64
> 2021-01-06 09:55:57.571198: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
> 2021-01-06 09:55:57.571216: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (ip-172-31-65-233.ec2.internal): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
> 2021-01-06 09:55:57.571389: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2021-01-06 09:55:57.607790: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2999980000 Hz
> 2021-01-06 09:55:57.608150: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x3d4d800 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
> 2021-01-06 09:55:57.608169: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
> 2021-01-06 09:56:15.612182: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:69] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0
> 2021-01-06 09:56:15.613446: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:356] Starting new session
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010348: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:816] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010388: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: Graph size after: 5850 nodes (5149), 13416 edges (12708), time = 182.03ms.
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010397: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: Graph size after: 5850 nodes (0), 13416 edges (0), time = 88.009ms.
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010404: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:816] Optimization results for grappler item: __inference_Preprocessor_ResizeToRange_cond_false_12695_58123
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010409: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0.002ms.
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010416: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0ms.
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010422: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:816] Optimization results for grappler item: __inference_Preprocessor_ResizeToRange_cond_true_12694_56958
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010428: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0.002ms.
> 2021-01-06 09:56:16.010433: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0.001ms.
> [ ERROR ]  Cannot infer shapes or values for node "StatefulPartitionedCall/Preprocessor/ResizeToRange/cond".
> [ ERROR ]  Function __inference_Preprocessor_ResizeToRange_cond_true_12694_56958 is not defined.
> [ ERROR ]
> [ ERROR ]  It can happen due to bug in custom shape infer function <function tf_native_tf_node_infer at 0x7f1fbc2c8050>.
> [ ERROR ]  Or because the node inputs have incorrect values/shapes.
> [ ERROR ]  Or because input shapes are incorrect (embedded to the model or passed via --input_shape).
> [ ERROR ]  Run Model Optimizer with --log_level=DEBUG for more information.
> [ ERROR ]  Exception occurred during running replacer "REPLACEMENT_ID" (<class 'extensions.middle.PartialInfer.PartialInfer'>): Stopped shape/value propagation at "StatefulPartitionedCall/Preprocessor/ResizeToRange/cond" node.
> For more information please refer to Model Optimizer FAQ, question #38. (https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Model_Optimizer_FAQ.html?question=38#question-38)

Debug log file: [Debug_Log][1]

Model Folder: [Model][2]
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VFlAW7C0RhmL-T1HrKwBMrvQzJNvCql7/view?usp=sharing
[2]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kkbp9fAXXsiDeq583Z0tV95zIfbI9_-N?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, please take note that **only these OS are supported by OpenVINO**:

Ubuntu 18.04.x long-term support (LTS), 64-bit

CentOS 7.6, 64-bit (for target only)

Yocto Project v3.0, 64-bit (for target only and requires    modifications)

Windows 10

Raspbian* Buster, 32-bit

Raspbian* Stretch, 32-bit

MacOS

Based on your OS, make sure that you had setup OpenVINO correctly and you are able to run the sample application as in [here](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/installation_guides.html)

Once you got that ready,
Cross-check your Tensorflow topology and see whether it's listed [here](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_TensorFlow.html)

Models and topologies listed there are supported by OpenVINO.

You may proceed to the next step according to the guide above once you are sure of yours.

NOTE: Please ensure that you had run the setupvars and able to see the initialization message each time you open a new terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. the topology i used isn't listed under the supported topologies.